# PHP cURL json response from Spotify

Tags: php, json, curl, spotify

I'm trying to get information from the Spotify API. When accessing this URL in my browser, it all works perfect; https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Led%20Zeppelin%20Kashmir&type=track

However, then I use this code to try to get the data I'm just getting a white page. I've Googled and searched Stackoverflow, but still no cigar. Does anyone know why this code doesn't work?

Appreciate any help on this.

```
$artist = 'Led Zeppelin';
$title = 'Kashmir';

$spotifyURL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='.$artist.'%20'.$title.'&type=track';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $spotifyURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($json);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($json, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Turn on PHP errors ?

Comment: PHP errors are enabled. No errors are returned.

Comment: Check to see if the page redirects, if it does there is an option in curl to follow redirects.

Comment: `artist` and `$title` need to be urlencoded in the URL. In this case the problem is the space in `Led Zeppelin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL contains spaces. Use the following line instead:

```
$spotifyURL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='.urlencode($artist.' '.$title).'&type=track';
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks! This solved it for me.